# XML Validation of DTD Elements

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

Hey guys i've got a XML DTD code that is external but when i try and validate it, i seem to get an error. The code i have is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog [ 
    <!ELEMENT catalog (book)+>
    <!ELEMENT book (title, authors, year_published, ISBN, number_of_pages, price) >
    <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT authors (author)>
    <!ELEMENT author (first_name, last_name, gender)>
        <!ELEMENT first_name (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT last_name (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT gender (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT year_pusblished (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT ISBN (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT number_of_pages (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT price (discount)>
        <!ATTLIST price discount (yes|no) "no">]>
```

I know everything is correct but when i validate it the error message comes up:

"Markup declarations contained in or pointed to by document type declaration must be well-formed. Line 3 Column 4"

i've checked everything but i can't seem to get it working. Are you guys able to help?

Comment: Good question. There is the typo in "year_pusblished", but that isn't what causes the error. http://validator.w3.org/check seems to say this DTD is ok. Are you getting the error from Xerces? Maybe it has a bug?

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML; this is purely about XML validation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DTD Element Assistance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473171/dtd-element-assistance)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have used the http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/ tool, which issues the exact error message in your question and isn’t particularly helpful in other ways either. Generally, the quality of free XML validators is... varying. A better tool is http://xmlvalidator.new-studio.org.

If you append the following simple XML element and validate using the better tool, you get a better idea of the problems:

```
<catalog>
<book>
<title></title>
<authors>
<author>
<first_name></first_name>
<last_name></last_name>
<gender></gender>
</author>
</authors>
<year_published></year_published>
<ISBN></ISBN>
<number_of_pages></number_of_pages>
<price></price>
</book>
</catalog>
```

You get the following error messages:

Line 25 Column 17 : Element type "year_published" must be declared.

Line 28 Column 16 : The content of element type "price" is incomplete, it must match "(discount)".

The first error is easy: just fix the spelling `year_pusblished` (removing the first `s`) in the element declaration.

The second one is less obvious, but simple: you have declared the `price` element with `(discount)` as the content model. This would mean that a `price` element must contain a `discount` element and nothing more, and that would make no sense really (though it is possible, formally speaking, but then you would need to declare the element `discount`). You probably want to allow just character data as content (the applicability of a discount is specified in a `discount` *attribute*):

```
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
```